# Tidying text in a way compatible with tidy evaluation

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, tidyeval, formatr

I want to tidy up source code in a way that is compliant with tidy evaluation. Unfortunately, `formatR` does not preserve the `!!` operator.

```
formatR::tidy_source(text = "!!little_b", output = FALSE)$text.tidy
## [1] "!(!little_b)"
```

From Section 7 of [Yihui's formatR guide](https://yihui.name/formatr/#and-from-the-rlang-package),

> In a nutshell, tidy_source(text = code) is basically deparse(parse(text = code))...

But when I call `deparse(parse(text = code))`, the text is unusable. Actual behavior:

```
deparse(parse(text = "1+!!x"))
## [1] "structure(expression(1 + (!(!x))), srcfile = <environment>, wholeSrcref = structure(c(1L, "
## [2] "0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L), srcfile = <environment>, class = \"srcref\"))"
```

The desired result is tidied text:

```
"1 + !!x
```

A solution here would probably solve https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this deparser issue you can supply the functional form:

```
formatR::tidy_source(text = "`!!`(little_b)", output = FALSE)$text.tidy
```

Note that you need rlang 0.2.0 that will soon be on CRAN.

We've been working on our own deparser that could perhaps be used in formatR in the future, e.g. `rlang::expr_deparse()`. We'll also try and see if R core would accept a patch to the base deparser to avoid this unnecessary wrapping in parentheses.

Also check out the [styler](https://github.com/r-lib/styler) package that should handle `!!` off the bat. It's now the preferred package for formatting R code and it is very configurable.